# Symlinking extensions on multi domain installs

Tags: extension

When installing extensions on a multi domain install is it possible to use symlinks to the code? For example:

download code to 
www/site1/sites/all/extensions/the_extension

and symlink to the above like
www/site2/sites/all/extension/the_extension -> www/site1/sites/all/extensions/the_extension

I assume if the server is set up to follow symlinks and extension files are all read only then this shouldn't be a problem?